# Assign Regex object to html input pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I need to assign a regex object to an input element pattern attribute programmatically.
Below is my current implementation:

```js
var regex = /\d{5}/;
element.attr("pattern", regex.toString().slice(1,-1);
```

Is there a better way to do this without string manipulation?

Comment: Are you using the `regex` object for anything else? If not you can obviously just assign the string directly with `element.attr("pattern","\\d{5}")`.

Comment: `RegExp` instances have a [`source` property](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.7.1) which contains their text, so `/\d{5}/.source === "\\d{5}"`.

Comment: @nnnnnn—there is no need to quote the backslash, `\d{5}` should do (and does in Firefox).

Comment: if you are using html5 why not use the data api

Comment: @RobG - In a string literal (as in my previous comment) you need to escape the backslash, including in FF. In a regex literal you don't escape backslashes. (I know that you know this...)

Comment: Yes, but testing in Firefox shows the value can be set to "\d{5}" per the literal syntax, which is also returned by [`regExpInstance.source`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.7.1). Not sure it's a big issue, either format works in FF, wider testing will reveal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`RegExp` instances have a [`source` property](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.7.1) which contains their text:

> The value of the source property is a String in the form of a Pattern representing the current regular expression.

Therefore

```
/\d{5}/.source === "\\d{5}"
```

so your code could be changed to

```
var regex = /\d{5}/;
element.setAttribute("pattern", regex.source);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery, use `prop` instead of `attr`. Becasue in newer version of jQuery, `attr` is readonly, `prop` is read/write.

```
element.prop('pattern', regex.toString().slice(1,-1));
```

Comment: What's the `.data()` method? If you're going to assume jQuery you can just save the regex directly as an object...

Comment: i dont see anything wrong with this. setting a data attribute is better than setting an element attr

Comment: @mkoryak - OP asked about the html5 `pattern` attribute, which actually has an effect on how the input element behaves. Changing that to a non-attribute data property doesn't help.

Comment: Why do you assume jQuery? It isn't a tag, nor in the question or the code.

Comment: Didn't know about the "html5 pattern" attribute. Learned something.