# adding regular expression to js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i add pattern="[0-9]+" to the div in this js code ?

```
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
e.preventDefault();
if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
    x++; //text box increment
    $(wrapper).append('<div class="delivery-num-input"><input type="text"  pattern="[0-9]+" class="form-control delivery_number_plus"/><a href="#" class="remove_field btn btn-sm btn-danger">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
}
});
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "add to the div"?

Comment: @Shubham I guess `pattern` property is only applicable to input types, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

As it's said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15491037/4627980). You can add programmatically the pattern to the input like this:

```
var regex = /\d+/;
var element = wrapper.find('input');
element.setAttribute("pattern", regex.source);
```